# using sleep and clear command in bash script

Tags: bash

I am learning Bash script.

Inside my script, I've tried `clear` and `sleep 1`.

`sleep 1` runs as expected but `clear` runs with `command not found` error.

Why is that?

clear and sleep 1 are enclosed within backslashes in my script. Stack Overflow is using those symbols to indicate code, and I don't know how to use escape symbols to type them here.

Comment: Run "which clear" from the console and paste your output. Please also paste your whole script ... I should be able to help you pretty quickly.

Comment: To type code on stack overflow, after a newline, precede your code sample with 4 spaces

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are trying this :

```
$(clear)
```

Or this

```
`clear`
```

These are two ways of expression command substitution.  The first one is more readable and should be preferred, but they do the same thing.

The solution is to simply use this:

```
clear
```

Now, if you are interested in understanding why you are getting this error, here is a longer explanation.

Command substitution captures the output of the command enclosed -- the output of standard output (file descriptor 1), not standard error (standard error), to be more precise -- and then provides this output as a string to be used as part of the command where it was found, as if it had been part of the command to start with (but not subject to further expansions).

The `clear` command has a special output that causes the terminal screen to clear.  But by enclosing `clear` in backticks, this special output is not sent to the terminal (the terminal does not clear), and it is instead captured by the command substitution.  Then, this special output is provided as if it had been typed on the command line, and since it is the first (and only) thing on that line, the shell tries to find a command with a name equal to that special character, which it does not find, and that is where you get the "command not found" error.

Just for fun, try this :

```
$(clear >&2)
```

It will clear the screen, and not trigger an error, because the output is redirected to file descriptor 2 (standard error), which is not captured by the command substitution and actually is sent to the terminal (which clears), and since there is no other output, the command substitution evaluates to an empty string, which Bash interprets as a request to do nothing (Bash does not try to find a command with a zero-length name).

I hope this helps you understand the reason you are getting this error.

Comment: Absolute travesty that this had no upvotes - a brilliant answer

Answer (score 0):

The backquotes are used in Stack Overflow indicating the a string should be shown as code. Your real code doesn't need backquotes:

```
echo "Hello from commandline"
sleep 3
echo "After sleeping, will try to use clear in 4 seconds"
sleep 1
echo "will try to use clear in 3 seconds"
sleep 1
echo "will try to use clear in 2 seconds"
sleep 1
echo "will try to use clear in 1 seconds"
sleep 1
clear
```

When you have seen backquotes in Unix code, you see an old fashioned way to call another command during the execution of a command.

```
echo "Current time is `date`, so hurry!"
```

Now we write this as

```
echo "Current time is $(date), so hurry!"
```

It is one char more in this simple case, but much better when nesting more things. I will not even try to write the next example with backquotes

```
echo "Previous command returned $(echo "Current time is $(date), so hurry!")."
```